# AngularJS set dynamic key in array input

Tags: php, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS

And i have trouble to set dynamic key value.

Here is my code,

**VIEW**

```
<td>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="title[id]" />
</td>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.update = function() {
    $http({
        url: 'update.php',
        method: "POST",
        data: $scope.title
    }).success(function (data) {});
}
```

**PHP**

```
[amount] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 
        [2] => 
        [3] => 
        [4] => 
        [5] => 
        [6] => 
        [7] => 
        [8] => 
        [9] => 10
        [10] => 
        [11] => 
        [12] => 12
    )
```

So, my question is if i use `id` as input array key then always array start with `0` index not specific index.

Thank you !

Comment: What is id here? Please make it more clear. Can you provide more code.

Comment: Please check console : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bkUEu/5120/)

Comment: If I am right then you want to set your $scope.name with the given id (like 12 here) and the array should not be start with 0. Am I right?

Comment: check my answer on your other question, it should solve this one as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48032358