# AngularJS set dynamic key in array element

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I have trouble to set dynamic array key.

Here is my code,

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <form ng-submit="sendPost()">
        <input ng-model="newName[12]"/>
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.hello = {name: "Boaz"};
    $scope.newName = [];
    $scope.sendPost = function() {
            console.log($scope.newName);
    }                   
})
```

**Expected Output**

```
[12] => 13 (Input value)
[15] => 14 (Input value)
```

> **Que** By setting dynamic input array key i can get empty key values.

[image: Empty Object]

Also you can check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bkUEu/5121/).

In this fiddle you can get empty object keys in console.

Thank you !

Comment: why are specifying 12 in `ng-model="newName[12]"`?

Comment: @OmarEinea It is my primary id for use it while update record.

Comment: why did you tag php?

Comment: @DhairyaLakhera okay i removed that

Comment: so what is your expected result?

Comment: @OmarEinea i don't want empty object. Please check edited question.

Comment: `newName[12]` is one of the weirdest things I've seen today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want the keys that have been set to exist in the data you send to your server, then use an object instead of an array. like so:

```
$scope.newName = {};
```

Instead of:

```
$scope.newName = [];
```

This way, what's sent to the server would be:

```
{
    12: "Input value",
    15: "Input value"
}
```

I hope this is what you're looking for.